# Rails "noticed gem" saying uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

I am trying to get notifications to work in my app. I found "noticed gem" from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/excid3/noticed) and followed all the steps that he does. I have the gem in my gem file, I did bundle install and update and rails db:migrate and everything. However when I try running this in rails console

```
CommentNotification.with(post: @post).deliver(current_user)
```

I get

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from (irb):1
NameError (uninitialized constant CommentNotification)
```

This is my comment_notification.rb class that gets generated under app/notifications/comment_notificaiton.rb when I run `rails generate noticed:notification CommentNotification` just as he does in the video and just as the documentation suggests.

```
# To deliver this notification:
#
CommentNotification.with(post: @post).deliver_later(current_user)
CommentNotification.with(post: @post).deliver(current_user)

class CommentNotification < Noticed::Base
  # Add your delivery methods
  #
  deliver_by :database
  # deliver_by :email, mailer: "UserMailer"
  # deliver_by :slack
  # deliver_by :custom, class: "MyDeliveryMethod"

  # Add required params
  #
  param :post

  # Define helper methods to make rendering easier.
  #
  def message
    t(".message")
  end
  #
  def url
    post_path(params[:post])
  end
end
```

Comment: [reload!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393445/nameerror-uninitialized-constant-rails) ?

Comment: It doesn't work. I have tried reload!, and restarting the console all together, and VSCode itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to restart your spring server.

Using `bin/spring stop` command, the spring server will be stopped. Then the server will be started using `rails server` or `rails s`.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to this, but manually loading the notification class in rails console solved this issue in my case, i.e.: `load "app/notifications/comment_notification.rb"`. (PS: I would also check the spelling of the file name, i.e. comment_notification vs comment_notificaiton)

Answer (score -1):

Uncomment the first two lines:

```
# CommentNotification.with(post: @post).deliver_later(current_user)
# CommentNotification.with(post: @post).deliver(current_user)
```

remember, @post must be the resource that you are going to store in user notifications

```
user.notifications
```

@post must exist