# NameError (uninitialized constant Error) in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, uninitialized-constant, zeitwerk

I recently upgraded my rails application to rails 7 and after upgrading when I try to call the call from the lib folder I am getting this error `NameError (uninitialized constant Error)`

I have following file structure in the lib folder

```
lib
 -> a
 -> b
 -> c
 -> d
 -> error
    -> test_errors.rb
```

whenver I call `Error::TestErrors` I got this error, I guess this error is something related to the Zeitwerk

Can someone please help me with this

whenver I call `Error::TestErrors` I got this error ideally this should work and as it is working on the another branch

Comment: `lib` has not autoloaded by default in Rails since Rails 3. You either should require this code explicitly, move the code to `/app` which is autoloaded or add `lib` to the autoloading paths (not recommended). https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#config-autoload-paths

Comment: Does your application have `lib` in the autoload paths? You can inspect `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` in a console, for example. What is "the other branch"?

Comment: @XavierNoria By another branch I mean, It is working on the master branch where the app is still on the rails 6 and yes `lib`  folder is present in `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths`

Comment: Is the other branch running in zeitwerk or classic mode?

Comment: Also, when `Error::TestErrors` raises, is it referenced in an initializer?

Comment: @XavierNoria Yes another branch is running in classic mode. coming to your second question, No it is not referenced in the initializer it is declared inside the lib folder

Comment: Question is not where is defined or declared, question is where is referenced, where is the constant being _used_ and triggering `NameError`. Does that happen in an initializer?

Comment: @XavierNoria It is used at multiple places in the app/controllers and app/model

Comment: But that does not respond to what I asked :). Is `NameError` being raised from an initializer? I wonder if you are hitting https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-when-the-application-boots.

Comment: Mention of this in the upgrade guide here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#autoloading-during-initialization

Answer (score 3):

The constant `Error::TestErrors` was autoloaded in Rails 6.x. Therefore, `lib` seems to be in the autoload paths and `lib/error/test_errors.rb` seems to define the expected constant.

The exception that you get is `NameError`, therefore, this constant is not being autoloaded. If it was, you'd get `Zeitwerk::NameError`. This constant seems to be accessed prematurely, when autoloading is still not ready.

We do not have enough evidence, but it is very likely the problem is simply that this constant is being referenced while the application boots, perhaps in an initializer. This has been deprecated since Rails 6.0, and removed in Rails 7.0. This is a conceptual change in Rails, unrelated to Zeitwerk.

If that was right, please, have a look at [this section](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#autoloading-during-initialization) of the upgrading guide to understand how to update the initializer.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Using your link I could find this and the first option worked for me. -> https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-when-the-application-boots